# top bar zIndex / SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a ScrollView, but I want it to go under the Stack I created at the top.I do not know how to do it.Let the upper safe area be in the upper stack
[image]

```
 VStack{
      HStack{
           Spacer()
            Text("Picture")
           .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 50))
           .padding()
           .foregroundColor(Color.white)
           .shadow(color: .white, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
            Spacer().overlay(
        HStack {
         Image("1coin").resizable()
         .foregroundColor(Color.white)
         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         .frame(width:30, height: 30)
        Text("123")
        .font(.custom("Pacifico-Regular",size: 20))
          .foregroundColor(Color.white)
             
               }      , alignment: .trailing)
               
                }.background(Color.red)
                
                Spacer().frame(height:geometry.size.height / 15)//resim üst boşluk
                
            }
        ScrollView(.vertical){//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear you complete hierarchy, but you can either

a) put scroll view at bottom

```
ScrollView(.vertical){
 // .. content
}.zIndex(-1)
```

or if scroll view and header (HStack) is on one container (say VStack) then

b) put header at top, like

```
HStack {
  // .. content here
}.zIndex(1)
```

Note: by default all views are with `zIndex(0)`